# Split Excel worksheet into multiple worksheets based on a column with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Question is simple and may be repetitive.

1. I have an Excel workbook which contains around 50 columns
2. I have a criteria column for splitting this workbook into mulitple workbooks

The approach is as shown below

```
Name    SportGoods    quantity
ABC     CRICKETBAT    10
DEF     BaseballBat   20
GHI     football      30 
MNO     gloves        10
PQR     shoes         10 
ABCD    CRICKET SHOES 10
DEFG    BaseballBat   20
GHIL    football      30 
MNOP    gloves        10
PQRS    shoes         10
```

I am looking for a macro which enables me to create multiple Excel workbooks based on the column *SportGoods* like:

- Excel/CSV for all Cricket Items like CRICKETBAT, CRICKET SHOES, Gloves
- Excel/CSV for all football items like football and shoes

As input parameter I would be providing distinct cricket items, distinct football items.
Source would be a large Excel data sheet which contains ~5000 records.

Can someone help me with a macro which would help in generating multiple workbooks based on the above details?

Answer (score 4):

### Summary

This is a short, but smart macro. It splits & saves the data on the active sheet into different CSV files. The newly created files are stored in a new folder called *CSV output* at the same location as your Excel file.

---

### VBA macro

```
Sub GenerateCSV()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

iCol = 2                                '### Define your criteria column
strOutputFolder = "CSV output"          '### Define your path of output folder

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet       '### Don't edit below this line
Set rngLast = Columns(iCol).Find("*", Cells(1, iCol), , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
ws.Columns(iCol).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
Set rngUnique = Range(Cells(2, iCol), rngLast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If Dir(strOutputFolder, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then MkDir strOutputFolder
For Each strItem In rngUnique
  If strItem <> "" Then
    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=strItem.Value
    Workbooks.Add
    ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=[A1]
    strFilename = strOutputFolder & "\" & strItem
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
  End If
Next
ws.ShowAllData

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

<sup>Save it in a new VBA module</sup>

---

### Understanding the code

```
iCol = 2                               
strOutputFolder = "CSV output"
```

The first line is your criteria column. A `1` would stand for column A, `2` for column B and so on.
Second, we define a folder name where all our CSV files should be saved at. You can also set a fully qualified path like `C:\some\folder`. Otherwise Excel will create a folder at your Excel file's location

```
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

Here we save our current workbook and worksheet in a variable. Its not neccessarry to do this, but since we are dealing with multiple workbooks (newly created ones) I recommend this

```
Set rngLast = Columns(iCol).Find("*", Cells(1, iCol), , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
ws.Columns(iCol).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True   
Set rngUnique = Range(Cells(2, iCol), rngLast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Ok, what does this part? First, we search the last cell only in the criteria column. This must be done before our filtering and is needed later. Then, we use the famous *advanced filter* method to filter out in place all duplicate values from our criteria column. At last, we save all *visible* cells in a variable called *rngUnique*

```
If Dir(strOutputFolder, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then MkDir strOutputFolder
```

Lets see if a folder called `CSV output` already exists. If not, create one

```
For Each strItem In rngUnique
  If strItem <> "" Then
  [...]
  End If
Next
```

Now, we start to loop through all unique values in our variable *rngUnique*. But empty values are skipped

```
ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=strItem.Value
```

An important line. We use the autofilter method and view all lines which match our current unique value. The old advanced filter gets canceled automatically.

```
Workbooks.Add
ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=[A1]
```

These two lines create a new empty workbook and copy over only visible cells from our input Workbook

```
strFilename = strOutputFolder & "\" & strItem
```

Here we put together the CSV path. We take the current unique value as file name. The extension *CSV* is appended automatically since we have chosen `xlCSV` as output format.
Make sure, your unique values do not contain invalid filename characters like `< > | / * \ ? "` or the corresponding CSV file won't be created

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

The last step is to save the current workbook as a CSV and take the variable *strFilename* as filename. The CSV delimiter depens on your regional setting delimiter. It's possible to [change the fileformat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx), eg. to tab delimited CSV or Excel 2003 workbook

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

The first line speeds up our macro a bit since Excel doesn't need to show every single step of filtering.
The second line suppresses annoying *File already exists* prompts. Later we enable those functions again

Comment: Tried to execute it (in Excel for Mac), while debugging I've seen that this line ``ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=[A1]
`` this line is not copying the data into the newly created workbook. Any advice please?