# How can I replace forbidden characters in a file names before saving in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

This will be very simple for somebody who knows VBA better than me. I used a code original provided by user Nixda on this forum to [split excel worksheet into multiple CSV files based on column value](https://superuser.com/questions/714132/split-excel-worksheet-into-multiple-worksheets-based-on-a-column-with-vba/714495#714495)  (thank you very much Nixda!).

My only issue is that some of these column values contain special characters (~ " # % & * : < > ? { | } / ) and therefore create an error when saving because the CSV file name is dictated by the column value and these are forbidden characters for file names.

Is there some additional code I can add to replace the forbidden characters with an underscore in the file name but **not** in the column value?

```
Sub GenerateCSV()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

iCol = 4                                '### Define your criteria column
strOutputFolder = "CSV output"          '### Define your path of output folder

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet       '### Don't edit below this line
Set rngLast = Columns(iCol).Find("*", Cells(1, iCol), , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
ws.Columns(iCol).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
Set rngUnique = Range(Cells(2, iCol), rngLast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If Dir(strOutputFolder, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then MkDir strOutputFolder
For Each strItem In rngUnique
  If strItem <> "" Then
    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=strItem.Value
    Workbooks.Add
    ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=[A1]
    strFilename = strOutputFolder & "\" & strItem
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
  End If
Next
ws.ShowAllData

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I wrote a post about [safely naming worksheets](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/dynamically-naming-excel-worksheets-the-headache-free-way/), you should be able to modify the code to safely name workbooks. You'll just have to figure out what is and isn't a valid worksheet name.

Answer (score 4):

To keep it simple, just add following rows to your code before `strFilename = strOutputFolder & "\" & strItem`:

```
strItem= replace(strItem, "~", "_")
strItem= replace(strItem, """", "_")
strItem= replace(strItem, "%", "_")
strItem= replace(strItem, "#", "_")
' and so long ...
strFilename = strOutputFolder & "\" & strItem
```

[UPDATED]
Well, as @Dave mentioned (and he is right) make it better this way:

```
Function ReplaceSpecialChars(strIn As String, strChar As String) As String
    Dim strSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    strSpecialChars = "~""#%&*:<>?{|}/"

    For i = 1 To Len(strSpecialChars)
        strIn = Replace(strIn , strSpecialChars(i), strChar)
    Next

    ReplaceSpecialChars = strIn 
End Function
```

... and then call it like this:

```
strFilename = strOutputFolder & "\" & ReplaceSpecialChars(strItem, "_")
```

Comment: +1 but @DavidTudor-Hall, I would advise moving the code duDE has given into it's own function which returns the updated string - something like this could be re-used in another applications and it's nice to have these types of functions ready for a copy and paste!

Comment: @duDE, I think your `Replace` function's second argument should be `Mid(strSpecialChars, i, 1)`. VBA returns and error about array expectation since `strSpecialChars(i)` calls for indexing that's not applicable to Strings.

Comment: Note the strSpecialChars needs to double the double-quote character for the string to contain the ASCII 34: `strSpecialChars = "~""#%&*:<>?{|}/"`